# UPDATE a column based on multiple tables filter

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have three tables say T1, T2, T3

My update query is like:

```
UPDATE 
     T1 
SET 
     C1 =  'Y'
FROM 
     T2 
          INNER JOIN T1 ON T2.I = T1.I
          T2 INNER JOIN T3 ON T2.IN = T3.IN 
          WHERE T2.A = 'A'
          AND T2.B = 'B'
          AND T3.APP = 'LOW'
```

I have tried multiple ways to arrange this and looked at multiple solutions but not able to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Join conditions don't need to be combined with "AND"... on line 3 you can take out the "AND T2" at the beginning, I believe.  Also, line 4 should probably start with a "WHERE" rather than an "AND", because you're no longer telling it how to join, you're giving specific filters.  Are you getting a specific error message you can post?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bad news is that Oracle doesn't support `JOIN` in `UPDATE` queries -- even when the syntax is reasonable (`AND` between `INNER JOINS` ???).

The good news is that you can do this using `EXISTS`:

```
update t1
    set c1 = 'Y'
    where exists (select 1
                  from t2 join
                       t3
                       on t2.in = t3.in
                  where t2.i = t1.i and t2.A = 'A' and t2.B  = 'B' and
                        t3.APP = 'LOW'
                 );
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have known this "Oracle doesn't support JOIN in UPDATE"

Comment: there was some syntax error while reproducing my sql here, that has been edited now.